# Как сделать проверку в onStartCommand

Tags: java, android

Делаю запросы через `startService` в `Service`. Как сделать проверку в `onStartCommand`.

Чтобы разделить запросы, типо если запрос с значением таким то делать одно, если с другим то другое?

```
intent.getAction
```

не работает, `null` выдает. Думал там проверку сделать но

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы запускаете сервис через `intent`. Положите в него какой-нибудь идентификатор в `bundle` и в методе `onStartCommand` доставайте этот идентификатор

Comment: А через flags разве нельзя?

Comment: Нельзя. Оно уже отвечает за другой функционал